# netty client reuses serverside bootstrap results in the requests never finished

Tags: netty

A Netty server requests to another server as a client for every request it receives. Almost like a proxy, except it does not forward the received message as it is. I tried to use the server `ChannelHandlerContext` to create a client, but the request never finishes.

In the last duplex handler, if `test`, the client receives response, otherwise the request haunts.

Server last handler:

```
@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    log.info("receive: {}", msg);
    if (!test) {
        HttpClient.clientSend(ctx);
    } else {
        FullHttpResponse response = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1,
            io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpResponseStatus.OK,
            Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(CONTENT));
        response.headers().set(CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain");
        response.headers().setInt(CONTENT_LENGTH, response.content().readableBytes());
        ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(response).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
    }
}

@Override
public void write(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg, ChannelPromise promise) throws Exception {
    log.info("write: {}", msg);
    ctx.write(msg, promise); // checked, it is success. but client never receives.
}
```

Client:

```
public static void clientSend(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    final Channel inboundChannel = ctx.channel();
    try {
        Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
        b.group(inboundChannel.eventLoop())
            .channel(inboundChannel.getClass())
            .handler(new ClientChannelInitializer(inboundChannel));

        // Make the connection attempt.
        ChannelFuture f = b.connect(host,port);
        Channel outboundChannel = f.channel();
        f.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
              @Override
              public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
                  if (future.isSuccess()) {
                      // Prepare the HTTP request.
                      HttpRequest request =
                          new DefaultFullHttpRequest(
                              HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpMethod.POST, "targets", Unpooled.copiedBuffer(requestBody,
                              CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
                      // Send the HTTP request.
                      ChannelFuture wf = outboundChannel.writeAndFlush(request);
                      wf.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
                          @Override
                          public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
                              if (future.isSuccess()) {
                                  log.info("write success");
                              } else {
                                  log.info("write failed ", future.cause());
                              }
                          }
                      });
                      log.info("channel listener connected");
                  } else {
                      log.info("channel listener not connected");
                  }
              }
          }
        );
    }
```

When `write` is called, I can see that `msg` is correct, and `ctx.write` succeeds, however, the postman gives:
[image: postman]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it looks like you missed to set the "Content-Length" header that matches the amount of bytes of your payload. Add it and it should be fine.